# Passing Input field type along with the value using json

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass my input field type along with the value of that input field. So far i'm successful in getting value of the input field to the adddata.php. But i cant find a way to get the input field type. Please help.
This is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>attr demo</title>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="adddata.php">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#submit').click(function(){
           $.ajax({
               type        : 'POST',
               url         : 'adddata.php',
               data        : {name:$('#name').val(),type:$('input').attr("type")},
               dataType    : 'json',
               encode          : true
               success:function(jsonData){
                   alert('Success!');
               }

           });
       });

   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my adddata.php file

```
<?php
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   $type = $_POST['type'];

   echo $name;
   echo $type;
?>
```

Comment: Why? tell us why do you need the type?

Comment: i want give users to add customized input fields to the form select like textbox field, date field etc. and once they add the data it should remain in form as permanat. So to retreve data from database as per the selected input field i want this. for example if one user data select date field and select a date, i want to display in that in the form in date field not as a text box. hope u got that.

Comment: Your code should work... check you added the type attribute to the input field. and don't forget that `$('input')` will match all input fields - try using something more specific such as `$('#id')`

Comment: Show all the PHP from line  1 to 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your don't need the ajax call since you are submitting the form - remove the script and replace with:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    // Before submit
    $(this).prepend(
     '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="'+$('input').attr('type')+'" />'
    );
    return true; // return false to cancel form action
});
```

Comment: i had already added the type as text in input field. Yes its alerts as text but it doesn't go to the adddata.php. Does that mean is there in problem in php code while retrieving.

Comment: Unless you are not showing us all - no, it should work - edit your question add your HTML or the JS generating the form and all the relevant PHP code

Comment: Also try using `$_POST['type']` instead.

Comment: just to be clear - are you submitting the form? and after page switches to appdata you got the error??? or is that happening in the ajax call? cause I don't see any debugging on you ajax or preventDefault...

Comment: yes im submiting the form and error gives in adddata.php.

Comment: thats i am looked for. i think i am good to go with the rest. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
data : {name:"'"+$('#name').val()+"'",type:"'"+$('#name').attr("type")+"'"},
```

**Update**

```
  $('#submit').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type        : 'POST',
           url         : '4.php',
           data        : {name:$('#name').val(),type:$('#name').attr("type")},
           dataType    : 'json',
           encode          : true,
           success:function(jsonData){
               // do staff
           }

       });
       return false;
   });
```

The `ajax` call was never made with the code as the form was getting submitted. There is nothing called `type` in the form. Thats why the error is coming. And also you are missing a `,` after `encode : true`.

Comment: it works for the value but gives an error for the input type.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\column\adddata.php on line 10

Comment: line 10 in adddata.php is.    $type = $_REQUEST['type'];